# How to calculate D(f) in the new lognormal and normal formula in this document : "Explicit SABR Calibration through Simple Expansions"?

Tags: sabr, calculation

I'm currently reading this paper "[Explicit SABR Calibration through Simple Expansions](https://papers.ssrn.com/sol3/papers.cfm?abstract_id=2467231)" by Fabien Le Floc'h and Gary Kennedy  and in the 3rd part when they introduce Andersen & Brotherton-Ratcliffe expansions, I can't manage to get the same results as they get with the parameters they use when the strike is different from the forward value. It seems like I have an issue with the value of my Γ(K) and/or the D(f). Can someone show the complete demonstration with the numerical values to get the value they get for these particular cases ?